# Get latest data but group by multiple columns

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following data in my database:

```
|ID | Name  | date     | Category
+---+-------+----------+----------+
|1  | John  |2022-12-01| CAT1
|2  | John  |2022-12-05| CAT1
|3  | John  |2022-12-12| CAT2
|4  | Artie |2022-12-13| CAT1
|5  | Artie |2022-12-13| CAT2
|6  | Artie |2022-12-14| CAT2
```

I need to get the latest date for each category per person e.g:

```
|ID | Name  | date     | Category
+---+-------+----------+----------+

|2  | John  |2022-12-05| CAT1
|3  | John  |2022-12-12| CAT2
|4  | Artie |2022-12-13| CAT1
|6  | Artie |2022-12-14| CAT2
```

is this possible? i have tried using groups by multiple columns but cannot figure it out.

[Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

i am not sure how to implement the answers from this